# I want to uninstall mavan

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to uninstall maven but how to uninstall I don't understand. How to uninstall maven. I have removed the path and mvn home but it is still present in eclipse.

Comment: has it occurred to you that your IDE might have an embedded maven?

Comment: Eclipse has its own integrated copy of maven. I would not recommend trying to uninstall that.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse:

Click on "Help" in the menubar, then click on "About".

In the appearing Dialog, click on the Icons below or in the text at the bottom.

There you can uninstall the maven plugin by checking checkboxes and remove them.

Better option:
Let it be, let it be, let it be...
I would advise you top learn how to use maven instead.

Greetings

Comment: Note: On macOS "About Eclipse" is in the "Eclipse" menu, not "Help"